# How to call unnamed function in a lua table? [from outside the table]

Tags: function, lua, call

> p={update=function(} print("hello") end}

I can call the function within p using p.update() outside the table.

How do I call unnamed functions though? i.e.

> p={function(} print("hello") end}

If I know the index of the function, 1 in this case, can I use that in my function call? like p1? I've tried some variations of this to no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `p.update` is just syntactic sugar for one-word string keys.

The more general way to index a table is to put the key value in brackets:

```
p[1]()
```

Comment: okay,  not sure what mistake I was making before but its working with the above now.